Twilio error while accepting the incoming call
Error of
@twilio_conversation…js?v=582255ec:11005 Uncaught (in promise) 
Error: Forbidden
    at Upstream2._callee$ (@twilio_conversation…v=582255ec:11005:27)
    at tryCatch (chunk-NHAX666J.js?v=582255ec:270:21)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (chunk-NHAX666J.js?v=582255ec:362:22)
    at Generator.next (chunk-NHAX666J.js?v=582255ec:297:25)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (chunk-NHAX666J.js?v=582255ec:10:28)
    at _next (chunk-NHAX666J.js?v=582255ec:28:13)
Show 8 more frames


When I try to accept incoming call made by twilio
async function acceptVoiceCall() {
  const conversation = 
    await client.getConversationBySid(selectedConversationSidForVoiceCall.value);
  const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
  await conversation.sendMessage('Voice Call.', {
        "is_signaling_message": true,
        "is_voice_call": true,
        "state": 'accepted'
  }).then(response => {
        // console.log(response);
  }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
  });
}
  

this is my accept Call function
I want to find where i AM doing wrong and try to manage call functionality.
